# background task questions

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-jobscheduler, android-background

I have been reading lately about how background jobs are done in Android (using Service, AlarmManager, JobScheduler, etc) and learned that these background task can go indefinitely even the app has already closed or device has screened off. I understand that the only they stop if they stop themselves or other components stop them.

Questions:

1. If I have a background job or an alarm that goes every 1 hour. Does it really runs forever until a component stop them? Is there an instance that the system will stop them?
2. What if I have periodic job or alarm that goes every 1 hour. Will they stop if I uninstall the app that started them? Cos I never read this part in any documentation.
3. Is there a way to check any running or pending background jobs/alarms in my device?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation that is given about background tasks in your question only applies to Background Services, that to only in Android API Levels below 26.

Google recommends using JobScheduler or Foreground Service to do some work in background even when app is not in foreground.

Coming to you questions

1. No, If your using JobScheduler or Alarm manager the system will trigger your job to do your work depending on device idleness and conditions mentioned by you but the system can anytime come and stop your work in between when the conditions are no longer met.

   If your are using JobScheduler it will inform you when system wants to stop by force so that you can handle it properly and reschedule  if needed
2. When the App is uninstalled every job or alarm that is scheduled or in-Progress will be destroyed.
3. Yes, JobScheduler does provide a function 'getAllPendingJobs'

Note :

- For works that should be scheduled or completed even when app is closed then try avoiding the use of Background Services or Alarm Managers.
  JobScheduler is much more better replacement.
- If you want to do some simple background work when the app is in foreground then try using HandlerThreads or AsyncTasks